# How to load data from Kafka into CrateDB?

Tags: apache-kafka, crate, cratedb

From the following issue at CrateDB GitHub page it seems it is not possible, i.e., the Kafka protocol is not supported by CrateDB.
https://github.com/crate/crate/issues/7459

Is there another way to load data from Kafka into CrateDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'd use Kafka Connect for integrating Kafka to target (and source) systems, using the appropriate connector for the destination technology.

I can't find a Kafka Connect connector for CrateDB, but there is a [JDBC sink connector](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-jdbc/) for Kafka Connect, and a [JDBC driver for CrateDB](https://crate.io/docs/clients/jdbc/en/latest/), so this may be worth a try.

You can read more about [Kafka Connect here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html), and see it in action in this blog series:

- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, and I wrote the above blog posts.*

Comment: We also think a JDBC connection is the way to go. 

Is there any information on the performance penalty when using a JDBC connection instead of a connector using Kafka Connect? Just to know if at long term the development of one is worth it.

Comment: That's a question for someone with CrateDB experience, which I don't have, sorry. I guess it depends how efficient the JDBC implementation is vs a native API.